# Unity- Как добавить частицы на курсор

Tags: unity3d, cursor, particles

У меня есть курсор, как сделать так чтобы частицы следовали за ним
(Примером может быть игра Ori and the blind forest)

Comment: Возможно, просто создаёте систему частиц и двигаете её за курсором.

Comment: Я тоже так думал, но частицы будут заходит за объекты

Comment: А у вас 2d или 3d?

Comment: У меня 3D игра.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из вариантов. **Работает только когда у вас 3D частицы.**

1. На пустом месте далеко за сценой создаете частицы, так чтобы их не было видно в камере ни при каких условиях. Возле частиц которые находятся очень далеко создаем еще камеру, в `Clear flags` ставим `Solid color`, альфу цвета выкручиваем в 0, ну и `projection` ставим orthographic. `Size` ставим по усмотрению. Еще выключаем в ней `audiolistener`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. В окне файлов проекта создаем `Render Texture` (Create -> Render Texture). Перетаскиваем текстурку в созданную камеру в поле `Target texture`.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Поставил 3д материал для частиц т.к. с 2д не работает*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. В окне иерархии создаем `Canvas` а в нем `Raw Image`. Задаем ей желаемый размер. В поле `Texture` Перетаскиваем нашу `Render Texture`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. После запуска можно увидеть что частицы уже на экране и анимированны.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Ну а далее нам нужно двигать `Raw Image` за курсором НО если у вас частицы тоже имеют эффект при передвижении (например у меня в системе частиц выставлено `Simulation Space -> World`), то нам еще прийдётся двигать созданную камеру и частицы. Чтобы было удобнее их двигать я помещу их в созданный пустой объект, который и буду двигать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
6. Пишем скрипт, который повесим на нашу `RawImage` для передвижения за курсором.

   ```
    public class MoveParticleRawImage: MonoBehaviour
    {
       private void Update()
       { 
         transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
       }
    }
   ```
7. Запустив игру можно увидеть что частицы следуют за курсором, Но эффектов вверх/вниз/вправо/влево нету.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
8. Пишем скрипт для объекта в котором находятся камера и частицы и вешаем скрипт на него.

   ```
   public class MoveParticles : MonoBehaviour
   {
     public float sensitivity = 4; // можно менять под себя для настройки 
     //чувствительности движения партиклов

     private Camera _camera;
     private Vector3 _originalTransform;


     private void Awake()
     {
         _camera = Camera.main;
         _originalTransform = transform.position;
     }

     private void Update()
     {
         transform.position = Input.mousePosition / sensitivity + _originalTransform;
     }
   }
   ```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

9. Запускаем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее можно уже кастомизировать под себя и т.д.